# How to perform meaningful comparison between two object which do not implement equals method?

Tags: java, equals

I am writing a test cases where I need to meaningful compare two objects which do not implement `equals`. I don't want to write `equals` or `hashcode` methods for these objects.

Is there an API which can do this for me?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to write an equals method *in that class* or you don't want to write the code at all?

Comment: Use assertSame() if you want to compare if these two references refers to the same (one) object. Anyway, you should implement equals if you want to test equality - Java is object oriented and that's how it should be done.

Comment: Developers still wait for a breakthrough in the research of *do-what-I-mean* algorithms ... a patent is worth a billion dollars ;)

Comment: It's difficult to determine what do you mean by "compare two objects". do you want to compare two instances of the same object, or two instances of different objects or... ?

Answer (score 5):

Apache commons-lang has an automatic equals builder - e.g. "reflection-equals". [API documentation for `EqualsBilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html). Also note that there is a [`HashCodeBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) in the same library.

---

Example using this library:

```
static class A {
    private int a;
    private String b;
    A(int a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a1 = new A(123, "Hello World!");
    A a2 = new A(321, "Hello!");
    A a3 = new A(123, "Hello World!");

    System.out.println(EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(a1, a2, true));
    System.out.println(EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(a1, a3, true));
}
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's just for test code you could just create a helper method to encapsulate your assertions:

```
public static void assertMyClassEquals(MyClass expected, MyClass actual) {
    assertEquals(expected.foo, actual.foo);
    //...
}
```

But I'm not sure I understand your aversion to creating an `equals()` method which could obviously be useful.

Comment: +1. And if the meaningfulness of the method extends beyond the usefulness in a test case, you can make it part of the application code itself (rather than the test suite).

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is look up the use of a comparator which should suit your needs perfectly.

A link to the JAVA API [Interface Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

And a link to a blog post explaining how to use it. [Comparable and Comparator interfaces-Part 2](http://java-espresso.blogspot.com/2011/06/comparable-and-comparator-interfaces_30.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes comparing the result of `toString` is a meaningful comparison.

Comment: The OP said he didnt want to implement his own hashcode method, which is pretty much what Objects toString method does.